# disable Opportunity.amount RSF calculation when opportunity products exist

Tags: opportunity

I need to know how to disable the amount field calculation on the opportunity detail so that it is not active when a product is entered OR disable pricebooks.  One of the other.  Any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If you add products to the opportunity using the standard OpportunityLineItem, the system will automatically calculate the new total. It is not possible to disable this functionality. You could either build a custom currency field to track a different type of amount, or you could deactivate all price books so that users can't add products to the opportunity; either way, you're going to have to do some customization.

Answer (score 0):

Default amount field on Opportunity is of type currency so it should not change depending on pricebooks or product.

If amount is dependent(changing based on  pricebooks or product) in your org then possible you might have trigger/Workflow/formula field due to which its changing.

You can try disabling trigger/Workflow and verify its not formula field to disable it.

Comment: Amount is automatically calculated by the platform.